# Sharing layout information between Jade and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have a Node.js/Jade-based site and I'm trying to add some interactivity with some simple bits of Javascript.

In particular, I'm trying to set up a button that adds a new row to a table.
The table rendering is currently done in Jade, and I'm planning on using JQuery to set up the callback to add the row.

My template looks something like:

```
tbody#my_body
  - each foo in foos
    tr
      td= foo.blah
      td= foo.hello
      td
        a( ... complex link stuff etc. )
```

And I'm thinking my JS callback will be

```
$("a#add_row").click(function(){
  $("#my_body").append( ??? );
});
```

I could rewrite the whole layout stuff in HTML in the `append` body, but that seems stupid. Every time I change one I'd have to change the other.

Is there a way of sharing the layout code between the Jade template and the Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, you have access to the server-side variables when you are writing the view. You could also do a dump of your models/variables to json and use that. Finally, you could look at Backbone.js and reuse the same models on the client/server. See [this post](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/).

Comment: I thought about Backbone when I was first designing the app. Unfortunately it's much more of a traditional site than a single-page highly-dynamic app. So while when editing stuff in the model an interactive approach would be nice, at the moment 90% of the content is perfect for Express. I'm not sure if there's a nice way to get the best of both worlds though. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @BenHumphreys understood, I guess I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by sharing code between the template and JS then.

Comment: In the light of day I think I get your suggestion better. I could abstract the table row-rendering stuff to a partial, then render the empty partial and put it as static text into my Javascript somewhere? Now I just have to work out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

So... I don't think I fully understand what you're asking. Do you want the table to be static between sessions or just within the context of a single session or refresh?

If it's the latter then you just add the table row via jquery like you would a site that was full html. By the time you're calling the jquery function express has already rendered the jade templates out to full html.

If you want that row to persist then you need to include a call to the server that adds that new row's data to your data collection for foo, then whenever the page renders again the server will pass foo back with all the prior rows + the one you just added.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I was wondering if there was some way that I could get the jQuery to retrieve part of a Jade template. For example if I had a mixin to render each row, and then it was somehow available to both the jQuery and the server-side rendering code. For now I've just copied the rendered output and put it in my Javascript callback.

Comment: I think TJ's finance app might give you a good start, check the [index.jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/finance/tree/master/views/item). Or his [screenr of the app](http://www.screenr.com/G6a). Is that the sort of thing you are trying to accomplish? You wouldn't end up using the append(), instead you pass back your data to the server and let it render out your newly updated jade partial that contains your table. You just keep going back and forth like that instead of just rendering on the client side.

Comment: So [this function](https://github.com/visionmedia/finance/blob/master/public/javascripts/main.js#L40) gets called and does as you said above? It means the server has to do a bit of work every time but it might be worth it in the long run. People aren't going to be editing that much. Maybe. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Exactly, generally if people are adding anything to the client side you want to add it to a datastore of some sort anyway so you might as well send it back to the server and let it render out the partial again. Besides that way you keep the server and the client in sync with all changes which allows for more realtimey stuff :)